# Office 365: need to redirect root domain to www

Tags: heroku, dns, office365, office365-apps

With only 4 options for DNS records for Office 365 (A, TXT, AAAA and CNAME), I'm hoping to get the http://example.com to redirect to http://www.example.com  My client is hosting the name servers with Office 365 and would prefer not to change DNS hosting providers to something like DNSimple.com (I would prefer that)

The web application is hosted on Heroku

Any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try adding a new A record..

The "Host name or Alias:" you just enter a @ symbol by itself.

Then fill in the IP Address and hit Finish.

Works for me.

Comment: Not sure this will work in the long term. We do not have a static IP address with Heroku, so we have to use appname.herokuapp.com as the method of pointing to the web app.

Comment: Worked for me:)